# On Windows CE how do I prevent my menu from covering up my form

Tags: windows-ce

I am having a problem where on some of my forms my menu bar is covering up my controls 
[image]

But there are also some instances where my controls automatically line up below my menu 
[image]

What do I need to do in my forms so that my controls always line up below my menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the ability of a control to adjust its location to below the menu requires the control to be dock to the form. If you are using non-docked controls you need to place them in side a panel and then dock that panel to the form.